# How to renew an expired let's encrypt certificate

Tags: lets-encrypt

I didn't notice my Let's Encrypt certificate had expired. I would like to renew it.

I typed the command below

```
certbot renew
```

But I got error below.

```
# certbot renew
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/www.algebra.live.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
Attempting to renew cert (www.algebra.live) from     /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/www.algebra.live.conf produced an unexpected error:     ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')). Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.algebra.live/fullchain.pem (failure)

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -    

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.algebra.live/fullchain.pem (failure)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -     -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
```

How can I renew this certificate?

Comment: Does `acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org` resolve on this machine?

Comment: How I do with acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org?
When I typed in Chrome, it went to website, and displaying below.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #97.3c96f648.1551051349.4da68e9
It is not a command on linix?

Comment: The only purpose was to determine if you could resolve the name in the environment where you experience the problem. I guess that works (assuming you really did run Chrome on the same machine).

Answer (score 2):

You can't renew a certificate for a hostname that does not have an address record in the DNS.

```
Host www.algebra.live not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

You need to edit your DNS records and add the appropriate address records for this name.

---

In addition, your version of certbot appears to be trying to do the TLS-SNI-01 challenge, which isn't allowed anymore. You need to update certbot before trying again.

Comment: I think the initial statement actually depends on which challenge you've picked. The HTTP-01 challenge obviously needs an address record (`A`/`AAAA`) in place but the DNS-01 challenge works regardless.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Oh it is worse, I re-read the question and it looks like it was trying to do TLS-SNI-01

Comment: Maybe? That would be a problem but, at least the way I read it, I rather get the impression that the error is happening entirely on the client side and suggesting that `acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org` for some reason doesn't resolve in their environment.

Comment: Hi thank you for support
I added like this. Type:A, Hostname:www.algebra.live, Value: directs to algebra.live, TTL (seconds):3600
Still same error is showing...